# how when I add any new section in the index.html document, it will generate a new navigation item dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, loops

```
 const sections = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("section"));
 for(section of sections){
 const listItem = document.createElement('li');
 navList.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

- what i miss here
- this is the task :
- If you useHTML collection of all your sections getting them with their tag name like:
- ```
  const sections = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("section"));
  ```

Then you can iterate over this array and generate separate

elements.

- This will make your code more dynamic as when you add any new section in the index.html document, it will generate a new navigation item dynamically.

Comment: What does your html look like? What have you started with and what have you tried?

Comment: html has 4 sections and a navbar and the list item has in it a link tag, they need from me a dynamic navbar that when you add an a section it generate a new navigation item, and they suggested to do that with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you add your sections by coding rather dynamically. Based on that you can do this:

```
const generateList = () => {
  let lis = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(section => {
    lis.push(`<li>${section.dataset.title}</li>`);
    // change "section.dataset.title" according your dom element to grab text.
  })
  let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  ul.innerHTML = '';
  ul.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', lis.join(''));
}
```

Comment: thanks for that , I am a beginner and I will try to understand that code.

Comment: and if there is a simple way to explain a little what goes her it will be so good for me, and also if that not bothering you.

Comment: thanks ,your code aware me to something and i did my task,thanks